# Which Side of the Plane has the best view of the Seychelles at SEZ?

Tags: air-travel, seychelles, sez

**Which Side of the Plane Has the Best View of the Seychelles when Landing at Mahe (SEZ) Airport?**

The particular flight I am taking is leaving Dubai and landing at Mahe and it is on Emirates, should this make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Approach to SEZ from the southeast, port side view.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOv0_JiM7PI)
- [Approach to SEZ from the northwest, port side view.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMJG8kdr-VU)
- [Approach to SEZ from the southeast, starboard side view](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPITD_3RCe0) (dullsville.)
- [Approach to SEZ from the northwest, starboard side view.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RCdA-x1ERc)

If you don't know ahead of time which way the plane will be landing, the port side of the plane has something interesting to see in either direction.  The starboard side looks even more interesting if you know that you'll be approaching from the northwest, but if you're approaching from the southeast, you'll just be looking at a lot of ocean.

As was noted in @Peter M's answer, the direction of approach is determined largely by the wind speed at the airport;  the fact that it's coming from Dubai is largely irrelevant.  All of the airplane in the videos above came either from Dubai or from Abu Dhabi.

Comment: To save googling time for those of us not familiar with nautical terminology: "port" means "left" and "starboard" means "right"

Answer (score 5):

That's going to depend on which way the wind blows when you land which is related to the time of year, current storms etc.    All you can do is guess the best side and hope that the travel gods answer your wishes.

But in terms of actual data you can make a decision on, you can see from [Mahé/Seychelles Airport](https://www.windfinder.com/windstatistics/mahe_seychelles_airport) wind and weather direction that you can make a reasonbly educated guess.

Comment: And how do I determine the side given the wind direction? That way I can at least look at predominant or historical data.

Comment: @Itai In general planes land into the wind. You know when you are flying and the link shows the predominate wind direction across the year.  Also you know what scenery you want to see.

Comment: > "In general planes land into the wind." It would be very useful to include this in your answer (although it's also Googlable easily enough)